# Is this a bug in Webkit? Translate with Overflow results in non-clickable content

Tags: css

I don't understand why `unselectable button` here is not selectable or clickable when the parent is `translate`ed.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/PmttQCLwcj

- in Firefox, the button is clickable (although, the text not selectable).
- in Chrome, it is only clickable at the very edge of the button (carefully hover your mouse to the left of the button).

Remove the `translate` class, and all behaves as expected - the text is selectable and the button is clickable.

```
  <!-- main -->
  <div class="absolute inset-0 overflow-y-clip bg-red-200">
    <!-- nav -->
    <div class="bg-blue-200 w-64 p-3 absolute inset-0 overflow-y-clip translate-x-5 ">
      <div class="overflow-y-auto">Lots of content that can overflow in the y-axis</div>
      <!-- toggle -->
      <div class="bg-green-200 absolute inset-0 left-[100%] ">unselectable <button>button</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I expect to be able to select the text and click the button with the mouse, because I can see it, but I cannot. The button is visible, and can receive the focus by tabbing, and it can be clicked with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's work !!!
you need to change position of div element, please check below link

https://play.tailwindcss.com/HDOPwIy1fe